# when i try to run my code i get that error "ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386"

Tags: iphone

d /Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SIPTabApp.app/SIPTabApp normal i386
    cd /Users/syedmatloob/Documents/SIPTabApp
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.3
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/syedmatloob/Documents/SIPTabApp/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib -L/Users/syedmatloob/Documents/SIPTabApp/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/lib/mediastreamer/plugins -F/Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Intermediates/SIPTabApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SIPTabApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/SIPTabApp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.3 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework MediaPlayer -framework Security -framework QuartzCore -lxml2 -framework CoreLocation -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -lsqlite3.0 -framework AVFoundation -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreData -framework SystemConfiguration -lavcodec -lavutil -lbcg729 -lcrypto -leXosip2 -lgsm -lilbc -llinphone -lmediastreamer -lopencore-amrnb -lopencore-amrwb -lortp -losip2 -losipparser2 -lSKP_SILK_SDK -lspeex -lspeexdsp -lsrtp -lssl -lswscale -lvpx -lx264 -lzrtpcpp -lmsamr -lmsbcg729 -lmsilbc -lmssilk -lmsx264 -lresolv -framework CoreTelephony -framework OpenGLES -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -o /Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SIPTabApp.app/SIPTabApp

duplicate symbol _SECURE_BUTTON_TAG in:
    /Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Intermediates/SIPTabApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SIPTabApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/IncallViewController.o
    /Users/syedmatloob/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SIPTabApp-augbivszmspykvenplsxyvefxkjw/Build/Intermediates/SIPTabApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SIPTabApp.build/Objects-normal/i386/InCallVC.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please reformulate and elaborate. This is absolutely unreadable as is.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a variable `SECURE_BUTTON_TAG` that you've defined in your `IncallViewController.m` and `InCallVC.m`. Depending on your code, there are a few options:

- If they are used only inside their respective .m files, prefix them with the `static` keyword to make them "private" to their compilation unit.
  ** From the name, I'd guess that it references a number. So make that `static const`.
- Remove one, declare it as `extern` in a header file.
- Rename one.